# How to config Boost logging filter in configuration file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm using Boost 1.63 in VS2015 on Windows 10.

The code is following [Boost example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html).

Here's code, seems the record generated by 'severityLogger.open_record' is NOT valid, it doesn't go inside the if-statement.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/locale/generator.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/from_settings.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/settings_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;

src::wseverity_logger<logging::trivial::severity_level> severityLogger;
std::wifstream strm(L"config\\logger.ini");
strm.imbue(std::locale(strm.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::consume_header>));
auto settings = logging::parse_settings(strm);
logging::init_from_settings(settings);
logging::add_common_attributes();

auto rec = severityLogger.open_record(keywords::severity = logging::trivial::severity_level::info);
if (rec) { // Unable to go here !!!
    logging::wrecord_ostream strm(rec);
    strm << L"Some message";
    strm.flush();
    severityLogger_.push_record(boost::move(rec));
}
```

However, it works fine if I add this piece of code:

```
logging::core::get()->set_filter(
    logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info);
```

Here's my configuration file:

```
[Core]
DisableLogging=false
Filter="%Severity% >= info"

[Sinks.File]
Destination=TextFile
FileName="App_%Y-%m-%d.%N.log"
Format="%TimeStamp% %Severity% - %Message%"
AutoFlush=true
TimeBasedRotation="00:00:00"
RotationSize=10485760
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default the filter parser does not expect an attribute of type `logging::trivial::severity_level`. As a result the parsed filter is not able to recognize the severity level and rejects the log record.

You need to indicate the attribute value type by registering a filter factory as described in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension/settings.html#log.extension.settings.adding_support_for_user_defined_types_to_the_filter_parser) section. Basically, this needs to be done for any attributes that have value types other than those mentioned in [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.predef_types) section. It is recommended to register all attributes, even those listed, because otherwise the library has to perform a more expensive lookup across all types supported by default when processing the filter.

You may also need to register a formatter factory, similar to the filter factory.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, problem addressed.